# When i run command docker-compose stuck at : db_1 | Version: '5.7.28' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Tags: django, docker

i am new here in docker, i am working on django, when i try to run docker-compose up, console stop after this message

```
db_1   | Version: '5.7.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Can anyone please help me what i need to do now to start my project ?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that explains how to reproduce your issue?  Make sure to include source files and logs as text in your question; please replace the screen shot you’ve attached with the text content of the log output.

Answer (score 4):

It does not stuck, but these are the logs from the DB container. look at the bottom of logs

> `[Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.16'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

Your container is ready to accept the connection.

If you need to run in detached mode then try to run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

You can connect to your DB from your application.